# How to use the span tag with sliderticks?

Tags: html

I have a simple slider with tickmarks and labels from using `class="sliderticks"`.

These labels rely on me using the `p` tag to get the ticks and text placed correctly. However it is also adding too much whitespace between the words in my
labels, so I would instead like to use the `span` tag which will create less whitespace between words.

Is this possible to do using the `sliderticks` class?

```css
    .slider {
        -webkit-appearance: none;
        appearance: none;
        width: 90%;
        height: 2em;
        background: #D3D3D3;
        outline: none;
        opacity: 0.7;
        -webkit-transition: .2s;
        transition: opacity .2s;
      }
      
      .sliderticks {
        display: flex;
        width: 93%;
        justify-content: space-between;
        padding: 0 10px;
      }
      
      .sliderticks p {
        position: relative;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        text-align: center;
        width: 1px;
        background: #D3D3D3;
        height: 10px;
        line-height: 10px;
        margin: 0 0 20px 0;
      }
      
      .slider:hover {
        opacity: 1;
      }
      
      .slider::-webkit-slider-thumb {
        -webkit-appearance: none;
        appearance: none;
        width: 5.4%;
        height: 2em;
        background: #FF0000;
        cursor: pointer;
      }
      
      .slider::-moz-range-thumb {
        width: 5.4%;
        height: 2em;
        background: #FF0000;
        cursor: pointer;
      }
      
      .slider::-ms-thumb {
        width: 5.4%;
        height: 2em;
        background: #FF0000;
        cursor: pointer;
      }
```

```html
<div class="range">
  <input type="range" min="0" max="6" value="2" class="slider">
  <div class="sliderticks">
    <p>Extremely unlikely</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>2</p>
    <p>Neither likely<br>nor unlikely</p>
    <p>4</p>
    <p>5</p>
    <p>Extremely likely</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Your widths don't match up. The slider itself is 90% wide while the ticks are 93% wide.
- The slider has 2px of margin around it. I've removed that.
- The thumb is 5.4% wide, which means your padding on either side of the ticks needs to be half that (2.7%). I also removed 2 additional px on either side because of your two ticks at the edges of the slider.
- Finally, your ticks need `box-sizing: border-box` to make the padding part of the total width, rather than adding it to the total width.

```css
    .slider {
        -webkit-appearance: none;
        appearance: none;
        width: 90%;
        height: 2em;
        background: #D3D3D3;
        outline: none;
        opacity: 0.7;
        -webkit-transition: .2s;
        transition: opacity .2s;
        margin: 0;
      }
      
      .sliderticks {
        display: flex;
        width: 90%;
        justify-content: space-between;
        padding: 0 calc(2.7% - 2px);
        box-sizing: border-box;
      }
      
      .sliderticks p {
        position: relative;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        text-align: center;
        width: 1px;
        background: #D3D3D3;
        height: 10px;
        line-height: 40px;
        margin: 0 0 20px 0;
      }
      
      .slider:hover {
        opacity: 1;
      }
      
      .slider::-webkit-slider-thumb {
        -webkit-appearance: none;
        appearance: none;
        width: 5.4%;
        height: 2em;
        background: #FF0000;
        cursor: pointer;
      }
      
      .slider::-moz-range-thumb {
        width: 5.4%;
        height: 2em;
        background: #FF0000;
        cursor: pointer;
      }
      
      .slider::-ms-thumb {
        width: 5.4%;
        height: 2em;
        background: #FF0000;
        cursor: pointer;
      }
```

```html
<div class="range">
  <input type="range" min="0" max="6" value="2" class="slider">
  <div class="sliderticks">
    <p>Extremely unlikely</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>2</p>
    <p>Neither likely<br>nor unlikely</p>
    <p>4</p>
    <p>5</p>
    <p>Extremely likely</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi I think you missed the point of my question, I am going to rewrite it to make it clearer -- I'm specifically interested in reducing the double-spacing of the slider *labels* created by the p tag.

Thank you for fixing the widths!

Comment: Well that has to do with your `line-height` of `40px`

Comment: No problem. Glad I could help.